# Flex: move one object to specific position with animation

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

- how to make one object move to a specific point
  with animation in Actionscript ( not MXML code ) ?
  ( Flex 4.5 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built in animation effects will do the trick (this moves is to 200,200):

```
<s:Move id="myMoveEffect" xTo="200" yTo="200" target="{objectToMove}"/>
```

Then you can play it with a call like so:

```
myMoveEffect.play();
```

So, here's a button that plays it, for example :

```
<s:Button label="move now!" click="myMoveEffect.play()"/>
```

Comment: You can of course create the Move effect in pure actionscript :)

Comment: yes, yes. i have done it... never tough that there is such a great class, solving the problem in very smooth way :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [effects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5fdc3-7fff.html).  You probably want the [Spark Move effect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/Move.html).

Comment: i read this both, but they explaining only for one direction - X. I need to move it simultaneously into 2 dimensions ( XY ). :|

Comment: @Yordan Yanakiev I'm not sure what you read; but check out the links I posted in my answer.  The Move Effect will move something on the X axis using xFrom and xTo properties.  IT will move on the Y axis using the yFrom and yTo properties.  There is no reason they can't be used in the same move effect.

Answer (score 0):

Tweening? Its a great way to move around objects smoothly. [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), just one of the many Tweening Engines that do similar functions, is designed to wrap that all nicely for you so you see and use practically no code.

In relation to other comments on other answers, Tweenling enables multiple properties of an object (or even many objects!) to be changed simultaneously.

Answer (score -2):

```
DisplayObject.x = 5;
DisplayObject.x = 6;
DisplayObject.x = 7;
DisplayObject.x = 8;
```

Etc...

Ps: Try using a time interval or a loop.

Comment: this is very far from the real answer. :| especially in Flash platform .

Comment: @Yordan Yanakiev This post is the hard way to do it; but essentially this is exactly what a Move Effect does "under the hood".